# how do I give a link name to an html table row?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a table with each row explaining something (an input command). In another place, I am saying from this state with that input command, you go that other state. What I want to do is to link the `that input command` to the appropriate row of the table. Imagine something like this:

```
...link to row number <a href="#row2">2</a>...

<table ...>
    <tr>
        <td>command</td>
        <td>description</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <a name="row1"></a>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>input A</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <a name="row2"></a>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>input B</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I tried putting a `<a name="row2"></a>` in the `<tr>` block but that didn't work (it brings me to the top of the table)

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You do one of two things:

1) Set the id attribute of the `<tr>`. `<tr id="row2">...</tr>`

OR

2) put the `<a>` element inside the `<td>` element. If you put any element inside a `<table>` but not inside a `<th>` or `<td>`, it'll get rendered before the entire table (try it with any element, the browser does its best to correct the invalid HTML)

Comment: The first method worked perfect. Quick question, if you put `id` in any tag, does that always also make an anchor at that location? Or is it just with `tr`?

Comment: Any element's id can be used as an anchor. I think it went in with HTML 4.01, and i think using `<a name='anchor'></a>` was marked as obsolete in HTML5. ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html)

Comment: The first technique works perfectly!  The second technique has the problem that the tops of some table boxes may not appear, especially if they are different heights and the anchor wasn't at the top of the tallest box.

Answer (score 1):

Although non-intuitive for me, but I put the `<a name="row2"></a>` inside the first `<td>` block and it worked!

Comment: <tr> does not contain anything but <td> (or <th> if within <thead>).  Basically anything you try to put in it other than <td> is ignored.  You can only put stuff in <td> elements.

Comment: Although this worked, but the problem is, the link takes me to the top of the text in that cell instead of the top of the row, so if I have cells that have multiple lines of text and all the cells are vertically centered, it takes me too far down where almost half of the lines of the bigger cell cannot be seen

Comment: That's correct - You can't put an `<a>` tag directly inside a `<tr>` tag.  As far as I know, the only tag permitted inside a `<tr>` is `<td>`.

Comment: a `<tr>` should have one or more `<th>` or `<td>` children

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
    <td><a name="row2"></a></td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>input B</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: This creates an extra column in my table

Comment: @Shahbaz yes, in fact, the first `td` is empty. I think what aus meant is `<td><a name="row2"></a>B</td>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a "dummy" anchor row:

```
<table ...>
    <tr>
        <td>command</td>
        <td>description</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 1px;"><a name="row1"></a></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>input A</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 1px;"><a name="row2"></a></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>input B</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

If you have styling on your table (borders, background, etc) this might be visible, but you could always style these rows like separators or camouflage them.